# Problem regarding webservices image cant displayed in the out put

Tags: iphone

```
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:elementurl];
NSLog(@"url %@", url);
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSLog(@"data = %@, length = %i", data, [data length]);
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
[data release];

iam not getting the data can any one suggest another method
```

Comment: can you post your NSLog outputs please?

Comment: also you are over releasing your data object (it is autoreleased so you don't need the [data release] line)

Comment: my nslog looks like this

2010-12-08 13:10:39.594 Imagzyn1[1951:207] width = 200 2010-12-08 13:10:39.595 Imagzyn1[1951:207] height = 200 2010-12-08 13:10:39.595 Imagzyn1[1951:207] X loc = 149 2010-12-08 13:10:39.596 Imagzyn1[1951:207] y loc 238 2010-12-08 13:10:39.597 Imagzyn1[1951:207] url www.9atoms.com/imagzynws/images/image005.jpg 2010-12-08 13:10:39.678 Imagzyn1[1951:207] data = (null), length = 0

iam getting image width, height, location and url but the data becomes nulll

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406274/problem-regarding-webservices-image-cant-displayed-in-the-out-put

Answer (score 0):

## pragma mark --------------------------

## pragma mark Load UserImage

-(void)loadUserImage{

NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

NSString *frameImagePath = [profileInfoDict objectForKey:@"photo"];

imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:frameImagePath]];
if([imageData length] == 0){
/*NSString *imagePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@/%@",[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath],@"no_image.png"];
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
[item setObject:image forKey:@"itemImage"];
[imagePath release];
[image release];*/
}
else {
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(imageget:) withObject:imageData waitUntilDone:NO];

}
[pool release];

}
-(void)imageget:(NSData *)data
{
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
userImageImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
userImage=image;
userImageImageView.image = image;
[[mAppDelegate.userInfoArray objectAtIndex:1] setValue:image forKey:@"Image"];

}

Comment: Actually image is loading from webservices so we dont know the name of the image also(......jpg)?how can it help me.... any suggestion

Comment: [profileInfoDict objectForKey:@"photo"] this is path of image in weburl and image can be png or jpg or gif , if there is not image on weblink then it show no_image that you save in you iphone aap

Answer (score 0):

The method you have used is good for small images. If you are trying to download big images it will not do it properly.

You can use the below code

NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:60];
    connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

To establish connection

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)theConnection didReceiveData:(NSData *)incrementalData
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection*)theConnection
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error

and above method is used to receive data, error handling etc...

Now apply your own logic by using this methods.

Comment: thank u raxit i am getting url from the webservices but i cant covert it in to the  image?

Comment: Satya you are getting url. But to download the image which is on that url. You need to establish the connection. I write down 2 line of code to establish the connection. Now you need to write 3 methods. In didReceiveData method you will receive the data. Than convert it to image accordingly your need